# UI pane that 'rolls out' above main ui? (button)

Tags: android

I want to add a button in the bottom right of my app. This button will be on (almost) every activity of my app..

Touching the button will roll out 4 other buttons to navigate to other areas of my app.

So, kind of like an action button (not action bar) at the bottom..

I am targeting version 2.1 of android..

What should I be looking at ? AndroidSherlock requires a 'too new' version of android.. Fragments were not introduced until 3.0 ...

Comment: Fragments are backported in the support library, you can use them down to 1.6. ActionBarSherlock requires 2.1., so you should be fine there too. Also I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for, can you attach a layout sketch or something like this to make it clear? Maybe you are looking for the [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)?

Comment: Ah! I needed SlidingDrawer, perfect thanks! Not sure how I can mark this as answer though.. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) widget.

> SlidingDrawer hides content out of the screen and allows the user to drag a handle to bring the content on screen.